# React popup based on widows width

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to change popup position based on width size.

I thought about listening on resize and update a state every time a resize is perform like this :

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.listenResize);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.listenResize);
}
```

And using setState() to trigger a render.

My popup is called like this :

```
render(<PopUp infos={this.props.infos}/>
```

Then I catch the position of the popup to define if wheter or not it is off the screen.

But, I can't get PopUp position since it's not rendered, and there are multiples PopUp (rendered from a map)

I also feel like this would burn performances

I need some advice!

Thanks you

EDIT : For example, I want to render a pop up left/top/right/bottom based on window size, if the pop-up is out of the window when it is at the left, it puts the popup at the bottom

Comment: we got nothing from your explanation

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking screen size every render, just give you popup component a percentage based width and center it with justifyContent.

I hope I explained it clearly if not please tell me, so I can explained with more detail

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear but one solution to use external Library.
You can use Material-UI Library (Dialog) for pop-ups and you do not need to worry about the window size as this is handled by the library.

Comment: Why the pop-up is not rendered? However, you should set the position of the pop-up before rendering. Make you calculation before render.